# Javascript return array from array of objects where property value matches

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a built in Javascript function or library to do the following:

```
const data = [
    { name: 'name1', type: 'type1' },
    { name: 'name2', type: 'type2' },
    { name: 'name3', type: 'type3' },
    { name: 'name4', type: 'type2' },
];
```

To search the following and return all objects where `type = 'type2'`

Something similar to `data.findIndex((i) => i.type === 'type2')` but returns all matches rather than first index?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

**Example:**

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'name1', type: 'type1' },
    { name: 'name2', type: 'type2' },
    { name: 'name3', type: 'type3' },
    { name: 'name4', type: 'type2' },
]

const result = data.filter(o => o.type === 'type2')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'name1', type: 'type1' },
    { name: 'name2', type: 'type2' },
    { name: 'name3', type: 'type3' },
    { name: 'name4', type: 'type2' },
];
let res = data.filter(({type}) => type === "type2");
console.log(res)
```